# Make the correct INNER JOIN when using a BETWEEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have this particular case I can't figure how to handle. I need a query where I get all date values between two date values on another tables, and right now this is my query

```
SELECT      h.hour_gkey, h.hour_time
FROM        Hours as h
INNER JOIN  ServiceHours sh ON h.hour_gkey BETWEEN sh.openhour_hour_gkey AND sh.closehour_hour_gkey;
```

So to explain it a bit further, the ServiceHours table has two fields openhour_hour_gkey and closehour_hourg_key that are integer, this two fields contain Foreign Keys of the Hours table and therefore they have time values, the hour_gkey(integer) its the primary key of Hours table and I need to show only the values of hour_time (date fieldtype) that are between the dates that correspond to those two fields. How could I do that

Using right now SQL Server 2014

Comment: It might be helpful to know which database system you are using.

Comment: @DaveCosta Edited question

Comment: You say on one hand that `openhour_hour_gkey` and `closehour_hour_gkey` are integers, and on the other hand that they contain time values.  Which is it?  I would suppose that they contain integer hour numbers (which are not time values), but if they really contain times then that may be part of the problem.

Comment: You are not selecting any columns from table ServiceHours.  That's not inherently wrong, but it doesn't seem as if the results would make any sense if ServiceHours had more than one row.

Comment: Perhaps the example has been made overly generic, but if it's sensible to select all the Hours between `openhour_hour_gkey` and `closehour_hour_gkey`, then it seems like the FK relationships there are probably a bit overkill.

Comment: Those two fields are foreign keys of hours, so If I match that field with Hours table I get a date from another column, the problem is that I don't know exactly how to limit this

Comment: `a between b and c` is shortcut for `a >= b and a <= c` (borders included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question to be "How do I select all of the rows of `Hours` whose `hour_time` values are between those related to `ServiceHours.openhour_hour_gkey` and `ServiceHours.closehour_hour_gkey`?"

I furthermore suppose that it is intentional that you are neither selecting any columns from `ServiceHours` nor filtering to narrow the results to those associated with a single `ServiceHours` row.  Thus, if there are multiple `ServiceHour` rows you will get a set of `Hours` rows for each one, with these sets not necessarily being disjoint, and with no indication of which goes with which `ServiceHour`.

In any case, you need to perform a join for each relationship you want to traverse, and for this query you seem to want another join to get the target data.  that might look like this:

```
SELECT h.hour_gkey, h.hour_time
FROM        
  Hours h
  CROSS JOIN  ServiceHours sh
  INNER JOIN  Hours sho
    ON sh.openhour_hour_gkey = sho.hour_gkey
  INNER JOIN  Hours shc
    ON sh.closehour_hour_gkey = shc.hour_gkey
WHERE h.hour_time BETWEEN sho.hour_time AND shc.hour_time;
```

I have written the `BETWEEN` condition as a filter predicate instead of a join predicate because that seems a better characterization.  For inner joins, however, the two alternatives are equivalent.  Note also that this query is semantically equivalent to @DaveCosta's.

Comment: I try to run this but gives me error because there is no ON condition on the first inner join, why does that happen

Comment: @Forcefield, evidently because SQL Server wants you to say "CROSS JOIN" if you do not provide an "ON" predicate.  I had thought that the ANSI standard permits `INNER JOIN` without `ON`, but that seems not to be the case, although some DBMSs allow it as an extension.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: For some reason this gives a set of duplicated results

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I think it could be done. I am not certain if the syntax is exactly right for SQL Server.  But the basic idea is, you would need to join from ServiceHours to Hours to get the actual open/close hour values, then select the rows from Hours with values in that range.

```
WITH min_max AS (
  SELECT h1.hour_time min_hour_time, h2.hour_time max_hour_time
  FROM ServiceHours sh
  JOIN Hours h1 ON h1.hour_gkey = sh.openhour_hour_gkey
  JOIN Hours h2 ON h2.hour_gkey = sh.closehour_hour_gkey
)
SELECT h.hour_time
  FROM Hours h
  JOIN min_max ON h.hour_time BETWEEN min_max.min_hour_time AND min_max.max_hour_time
```

(Note I'm assuming that ServiceHours has only one row.  If it doesn't, there is probably some other field you want to include in both the subquery and the main query to indicate which row in ServiceHours each resulting row relates to.)

Comment: ServiceHours should provide a single row only depending on a serie of relationships and conditions, but I don't know exactly how to make the first relationship, I will try to accomodate your code